# (F#, mono for OS X) Errors is happened in visual studio code but send file to fsi successfully (fsi:send file)

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I have got errors with the following codes in visual studio code. However, I am able to send the file with command (fsi:send file) and it is executed successfully. It seems I didn't setup the VSC with Ionide properly.
Please feel free to comment.

```
#load "packages/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.3.14.0-beta01/MathNet.Numerics.fsx"  

open MathNet.Numerics

SpecialFunctions.Gamma(0.5) // Unexpected identifier in implementation file

open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
let m : Matrix<float> = DenseMatrix.randomStandard 50 50
(m * m.Transpose()).Determinant()
```

Syntax check for mistakes and errors in vscode, but the code can be executed in fsi

1. This directive may only be used in F# script files (extensions .fsx or .fsscript). Either remove the directive, move this code to a script file or delimit the directive with '#if INTERACTIVE'/'#endif'
2. The namespace or module 'MathNet' is not defined.
3. Unexpected identifier in implementation file

Comment: What kind of errors? Please edit your question.

Comment: There's no way for anyone to give you a good answer with the details you've provided. We need to know the error message(s) you're getting. Edit your question and then we'll be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error, "This directive may only be used in F# script files (extensions .fsx or .fsscript)", is telling you how to solve it. You haven't told us the filename of your F# file that you're getting errors in, but I bet it ends with `.fs`, right? The `.fs` extension is intended for files that are part of a larger project. A good rule of thumb is that if you have any `.fs` files, you need a project file (currently that's going to be in `.fsproj` format, which is an ugly XML file, but VS Code can help you create it).

If you want to use the `#load` directive, it must be in an F# *script* file, which means a file with an `.fsx` extension. (The `.fsscript` extension is also allowed, but I never see anyone using it in practice. The `.fsx` extension is the *de facto* standard).

Simply rename your `.fs` file to `.fsx` and that should solve error #1. Then errors #2 and #3 should go away on their own -- they are happening because the F# compiler isn't loading the `MathNet` namespace, which is because it's ignoring the `#load` directive in a `.fs` file. Once the `#load` directive is processed, then the `MathNet.Numerics.fsx` file should be loaded, and that file in turn loads all the namespaces needed.

So this was simply because you saved the file as a `.fs` file when you needed `.fsx`.

Comment: I changed the file extension from .fs to .fsx. All errors have been gone. Thank you.

Comment: If that solved your problem, you should accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. That way anyone who finds your question later in a StackOverflow or Google search will know that it was answered *and* that the answer solved your problem. Glad I could help!